# Program hardware without Printer Port

Tags: hardware

My motherboard is small and don't have a printer port, all the tutorials (program LEDs, motor etc.) of hardware programming tell the use of this port or a USB to printer port converter to program hardware.
Is there any other way and any other port (for example USB) to program hardware?

Comment: Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to buy Arduino which can easily be connected to USB and use it's outputs as parallel port. Why parallel port is popular when working hardware? Because it can be easily controlled programmatically. With USB you can't just set certain bits. Bu Arduino comes with build-in USB support on one side and easily programmable output on another. Plus it is cool device by itself.

Comment: @LifeH2O if you is not going to throw any bucks then you will not be able to build anything. parts cost money.

Comment: I have some spare parts to experiment on, also i am planning to by Fez Domino but what about without buying this hardware

Comment: @LifeH2O there are two *easy* ports on PC: serial and parallel (you don't have this one). They are not used recently and I for example have none of them. So there is USB left. If you don't buy something ready made you will have to create your own USB device (guides can be googled, here is one http://www.create.ucsb.edu/~dano/CUI/) this is advanced task and will take much time. So buying Arduino eventually is easier.

Comment: It means that with only USB i can not program simple hardware? :( the link is same is creating arduino at home. I'll buy fez domino, thanks for advise

Comment: @LifeH2O yes, you can't directly connect USB to microprocessor, meaning you can't program *simple* hardware.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the hardware. If your hardware has a printer port (or parallel port, more specifically), you will need that one. If your hardware has a serial port (COM) which is quote common too, you need one of those. Some hardware will need the game/midi port that you used to plug in your joystick on your old 386 PC. I think convertors are available to convert USB to each of those ports.

Comment: the hardware is simple, leds, motors, many usb devices etc etc

Comment: You can't just plug any motor in an LPT port. It needs to have an interface. If it doesn't, you'll have to build that, and in that case, you can choose any port you like. Only exception is that the LPT port can deliver a little bit more power (I think) than the others, but when it comes to controlling motors, you're better of with a separate power supply anyway.

Comment: I have only USB port available.

Comment: Then it's better to first start and read a book about hardware. I got the feeling you think you can just plug a led in a USB port and be done, but that's certainly not the case. Please learn the basics first.